# Caching too aggressive showing unread total posts awaiting review which are not there

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review

Each time when I log in to the site, it shows there are some unread review items (4, sometimes 5), but most of the time there are always none (all zeros) when clicking.

> 4 total posts awaiting review

I believe the cache is too aggressive or something, as I didn't see this much on other sites. I've checked in *incognito* mode (without cookies) and it's the same thing.

[image: SE review unread count]

Anybody else has the same issue?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233535/review-counts-in-top-bar-and-review-dont-match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in [the MSE question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/233536/295684) linked in the comments, that indicator isn't calculated just for you. When you gain the "access moderator tools" privilege - 10K on graduated sites, 2K in public beta, 1K in private beta - you always see the total number of reviews pending *for anyone*. That is, even if the queues look empty to you (i.e. you reviewed each item already), that number is how many items are still awaiting consensus from the community.

Users with the edit privilege - 2K on graduated sites, 1K in public beta, 500 in private beta - but not the tools privilege will only see the number of items pending for them in the Suggested Edits queue.

Comment: Just a note: Privilege levels also change when going form private beta to public beta. I clarified for now that it is about a private beta, but you might want to add the public beta thresholds.

Comment: @wythagoras Thanks, I've added in the correct public beta figures from [this MSE FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/160292/295684).

Comment: In short, it is "by design" that when you hit the moderator-tools reputation level, the review counter becomes useless.